Детский вопрос о «Мессершмитте»
Вопросы у девочки возникли после просмотра фильма «В бой идут одни "старики"».
— Ребята, вот это номер! Кузнечик завалил мессер! [1:20 – 1:30]
С Кузнечиком мы "разобрались" быстро: это прозвище, поэтому кавычки не нужны.
А вот по поводу "Мессершмитта" вопросы остались:
мессер или мессера (не знаю почему, но нам хочется использовать второй вариант);
с большой или с маленькой буквы, в кавычках или без?

См. https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80&mode=all

Р.п. - мессера,  В.п. - мессер. Неодушевлённое же. Если бы шпиона Мессера "завалил", то было бы другое окончание. Без кавычек, т.к. латинизм скорее всего - мессер, мейстер, мастер...

И тут же закричал Скворцов:

Ребята! Вот это номер! Кузнечик завалил "мессер"!   https://www.leonid-bykov.ru/fight/scenariy10.htm?ysclid=lw1qx367hr606978726


В современной орфографии правильно: Кузнечик завалил мессер!
Но в сценарии: Кузнечик завалил "мессер"!
Пояснение
Мессер — условное название самолета "Мессершмитт", и здесь имя собственное переходит в нарицательное существительное. В этом случае написание со строчной буквы в кавычках или без кавычек, что определяется распространенностью и узнаваемостью слова. Сейчас название считается привычным и пишется со строчной буквы без кавычек.
Русский орфографический словарь: мессер, -а, мн. мессера и -ы (мессершмитт).

Почему хочется использовать форму Р.п.— завалил мессера? Это будет грамматическая метафора: употребление неодуш. сущ. в значении одушевленного.

Обратим внимание на глагол завалить — это скорее спец. слово из практики охотников: завалить зверя. Сбить рябчика — тоже форма Р.п. для одуш. существительных. Вполне естественно, что вражеский самолет напоминает опасную птицу и представляется живым.

Картина  известная, отдельные фразы часто цитируют, а сам фильм разобрали на мемы. И вот там можно увидеть: Кузнечик "мессера" завалил!

Пример: Артем Анфиногенов. А внизу была земля (1982):
…и тут Борис увидел «мессера».

О правиле и примерах разнонаписания
• Сначала мы посмотрели в справочнике Розенталя, где однозначно сказано, что правильно надо писать "мессер".

3. Официальные серийные названия летательных аппаратов (самолетов, дирижаблей, космических кораблей, ракет и т. п.) заключаются в кавычки и пишутся с прописной буквы: «Боинг-747», «Мессершмитт-109», «Фокке-Вульф-189», «Хейнкель-111», «Юнкерс-88», «Блерио-Х1».
В неофициальном употреблении те же названия самолетов (без цифровых обозначений) пишутся со строчной буквы: «туполев», «мессершмитт» («мессер»), «фоккер», «хейнкель», «юнкерс», «дуглас», «фарман», «летающая крепость», «цеппелин» (дирижабль).

• Потом посмотрели в литературе.
В названиях книг:
«Мессеры» против «Яков». Элитная иллюстрированная энциклопедия (А. Харук, 2013);
«Ишак» против мессера. Испытание войной в небе Испании (Д. Дёгтев, ‎Ю. Борисов, ‎Д. Зубов, 2012);
«Мессер» — меч небесный. Из Люфтваффе в штрафбат (Г. Савицкий, 2012);
Сталинград. Том третий. Над нами мессеры кружили (А. Воронов-Оренбургский, 2020).
В текстах:
Сразу же после того, как Радомски сбил мессера, он сам, как и Фриц Гутезейт, был подбит (Д. Дёгтев, Ю. Борисов, Д. Зубов);
Расскажу, как я сбил «мессера» под Пиллау (В. Гиляревский);
В частности, лейтенант Салкисов из 900-го ИАП сбил мессер в районе Разгуляевки... (Д. Дёгтев);
Суравешкин сбил "Мессер" (Г. А. Чечельницкий).
• Подумалось: а вдруг какие новые веяния?
Из-за этого разнобоя в написании, собственно, вопрос и образовался (не смогла я ребенку все разъяснить).

Откликнувшимся на вопрос — спасибо большущее!


с большой или с маленькой буквы, в кавычках или без?

Из справочника Мильчина:






мессер или мессера (не знаю почему, но нам хочется использовать второй вариант)

И не только вам.
См. пример (Неверов, Дмитрий Анатольевич. Хроника флотского спецназа / Дмитрий Неверов. - Симферополь : Таврида, 2004):




Добавлю немного обобщенной информации в соответствии с правилами Розенталя. Хотя формы без кавычек мессер, мессершмитт там не упоминаются, но они однозначно следуют из общей логики правил и соответствуют современной записи в словаре РАН. Так что Розенталь всегда прав))
Русский орфографический словарь: «Мессершмитт», -а (марка самолета) и мессершмитт, -а (самолет).
Тематические группы имен собственных с разными формами написания
 В этом случае можно выделить 4 формы написания:
 Форма 1. Прописная буква, без кавычек (в специальной 
 литературе).
 Форма 2. Прописная буква с кавычками (основная форма).
 Форма 3. Строчная буква с кавычками.
 Форма 4. Строчная буква без кавычек.

Форма 3 и форма 4 фактически относятся к нарицательным существительным. Наличие кавычек в форме 3 говорит о том, что данное слово пока не считается общеизвестным термином (но в дальнейшем изменения возможны, нужен контроль по словарю). Также может учитываться стиль текста.
Тема 1. Транспортные средства, бытовая техника
С прописной буквы с кавычками (форма 2) пишется большинство названий в этой группе: самолет «Юнкерс-88», автомобили «Жигули», «Рено», космические корабли «Восток», «Аполлон», холодильники «Самсунг», «Минск», стиральная машина «Индезит».
Летал на «Мессершмитте-109», на третьем боевом вылете был сбит над Кавказом.
При обозначении серии употребляется запись по форме 3 – строчная буква и кавычки: «мессершмидт», «юнкерс», «боинг» (серии самолетов).
Но повторного налета «мессершмитты» не сделали.
С прописной буквы без кавычек (форма 1) пишутся названия самолетов в технической литературе.
Из множества типов боевых самолетов, принимавших участие во Второй мировой войне, немецкий истребитель Мессершмитт Bf 109 занимает свое особое место.
Современный текст (форма 4). Владимир Тыцких. Через три войны // «Дальний Восток», 2019
Где-то у Бахмутово внезапно из-за леса вынырнул мессершмитт.
Тема 2. Названия  животных и растений
Распространенные и общепринятые названия цветов и плодов, а также породы животных, пишутся со строчной буквы и без кавычек (форма 4): иван-чай, анютины глазки, белый налив, китайка; собака болонка, корова холмогорка.
Эти же названия могут писаться в кавычках и со строчной буквы (форма 3): клубника «виктория» – неофициальное название.
Официальные названия сортов растений, овощей, фруктов, цветов в специальной литературе пишутся с прописной буквы и без кавычек (форма 1): клубника Виктория, тюльпан Махровый ранний.
Тема 3. Названия вин и продуктовых изделий
Условные названия вин и минеральных вод заключаются в кавычки, первое слово пишется с прописной буквы (форма 2): вино «Солнечная долина», «Бычья кровь», минеральная вода «Ессентуки-17».Также : конфеты «Мишка на Севере», масло «Слобода».
Названия сортов вин и минеральных вод пишутся со строчной буквы без кавычек (форма 4): кагор, мадера, портвейн, рислинг, шампанское; нарзан, ессентуки.
Названия марок вин в специальной литературе пишутся с прописной буквы без кавычек (форма 1): десертное вино Цинандали.
Ассортимент белых сухих вин: Цинандали, Рислинг, Алиготе.
Надеюсь, что этот материал поможет нашим читателям ориентироваться в теме.
